# AmbienLightSensor not supported

Tags: javascript

For a project I need to get the brightness (lux) of a camera in a web app via JS.

I've found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AmbientLightSensor. But using this on Chrome & Edge gives me that the API is not supported. Tried it also on different machines but keep getting the same. I also found this old code but it didn't work either:
`window.addEventListener('devicelight', listener)`

I have the feeling it should be possible to make since I can change soemthing in the settings to automatic change screen brightness which leads me to believe I have the right sensors.

Comment: Did you read/see the section on [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AmbientLightSensor#browser_compatibility)?

Answer (score 0):

First get the track then :

```
const capabilities = track.getCapabilities()

console.log(capabilities)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I need to set the flag in chrome://flags/ to enabled since it is something experimental!